# i want to submit multiple auto generated forms and then get values

Tags: php

```
include '../condbs.php';

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$mysql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boq_ WHERE level = '$lev' and class = '$cls' and subject = '$sbj' order by RAND() limit 0,10;");

$count=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
    echo'<form action="" method="post">';
    echo"<label class='qlbl'>".$row['ques']."</label>"; 

    $input = array($row['rans'], $row['fans1'], $row['fans2'], $row['fans3']);
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 4);

    echo'<table style="width:100%;"><tr>';
    echo"<td style='width:50%;'><input onClick='this.form.submit();' type='radio' name='answer' value=".$input[$rand_keys[0]].">". $input[$rand_keys[0]]."</td>";
    echo"<td style='width:50%;'><input onClick='this.form.submit();' type='radio' name='answer' value=". $input[$rand_keys[1]] .">". $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "</td>";
    echo"</tr><tr>";
    echo"<td style='width:50%;'><input onClick='this.form.submit();' type='radio' name='answer' value=". $input[$rand_keys[2]].">". $input[$rand_keys[2]] . "</td>";
    echo"<td style='width:50%;'><input onClick='this.form.submit();' type='radio' name='answer' value=". $input[$rand_keys[3]].">". $input[$rand_keys[3]] . "</td>";
    echo"</tr></table>";
    echo'</form>';
}
```

I want to get all these values on other page, but all above submittions in same page, how?

Comment: You can only click on one submit per HTML page.

Comment: your form action is empty. The code doesn't know about the other page, unless you have some other code in place you are not showing right now.

Comment: Simply make one huge form, and vary the names of your inputs.

Comment: i had been created table of questions, fielsd: rans(real answer), fans1(fake answe1), & fans2, fans3, then i selected questions randomly and answers too to put real answer on a different positions. the problem now is how i get sum of degrees from real answers, Do you understood my idea?

Comment: You could make use of ajax and collect all values in javascript object?